# How to insert this value into this table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have these 2 tables in Ms Access:

```
Items
RowID, Value
```

and

```
ItemRange
Value, RowIDStart, RowIDEnd
```

I want to insert a Value in Items table with a Value in ItemRange table within the range of RowIDStart and ROwIDEnd

How do you do this in SQL? I know how programmatically via Cursor (Open/Fetch) but not sure in pure SQL.

Comment: Maybe if you post your programmatic solution, it will help people to provide a pure SQL solution.

Comment: that is what I am thinking too.

Comment: where did the comments go?!!!

Comment: @dcpartners: please edit your question and post sample data and expected results. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I got your question right

but try this insert statement

```
INSERT INTO Items (RowID, Value)
SELECT RowIDStart, Value
FROM ItemRange
```

OR this one if you want to get both tables

```
SELECT ItemRange.RowIDStart, ItemRange.RowIDEnd, Items.Value
FROM ItemRange INNER JOIN Items 
ON Items.RowID >= ItemRange.RowIDStart AND Items.RowID <= ItemRange.RowIDEnd
```

Comment: You need to put Value into the range between RowIDStart and RowIDEnd